# "Guess my number" game with a while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I want to make a program that asks the user to think of a number between `0` and `100` and tries to guess it.

So this is my code so far:

```
k = raw_input('Think about a number between 0 and 100. (Enter/Return?): ')
x = 'a'
i = 100

if k == 'Enter':
    i = i/2
    while x != 'correct':
        print 'the number is:', i
        x = raw_input('is this the number? (bigger,smaller,correct): ')
        if x == 'smaller':
            i = i/2
        elif x == 'bigger':
            i = i + i/2
        elif x == 'correct':
            print 'Yupiiii!!'
        else:
            print 'Invalid answer'
```

My main problem with the program is that I'm not able to limit its "guessing" range.

For example: if it says `50` and I say its bigger it will guess `75`, then if I say smaller it will guess `37`. `37` is not a number between `50` and `75`; how can I make it guess a number in this interval?

It also goes over 100 if I keep saying `'bigger'`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation (using `-1` for lower, `0` for correct and `1` for higher), focussing on how to keep track of the valid range of inputs:

```
def get_int_input(prompt, min_=None, max_=None):
    """Take valid input from the user.

    Notes:
      Valid input is an integer min_ <= input <= max_. By default,
      no limits are applied.

    """
    ...

def guess_my_number(min_=0, max_=100):
    """Guess the number the user is thinking of."""
    print "Think of a number between {} and {}.".format(min_, max_)
    prompt = "Is it {}? "
    while True:
        guess = min_ + ((max_ - min_) // 2) # guess the middle of the range
        result = get_int_input(prompt.format(guess), -1, 1)
        if result > 0:
            min_ = guess # must be bigger than guess
        elif result < 0:
            max_ = guess # must be smaller than guess
        else:
            break # done
```

In play:

```
>>> guess_my_number()
Think of a number between 0 and 100.
Is it 50? -1
Is it 25? 1
Is it 37? 1
Is it 43? -1
Is it 40? 1
Is it 41? 1
Is it 42? 0
```

Note that making `min_` and `max_` parameters allows you to easily ask different questions:

```
>>> guess_my_number(1, 10)
Think of a number between 1 and 10.
Is it 5? 1
Is it 7? 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of both ends of the range the number might be in, not just the top.

Comment: So the initial guess is 50, and if the user answers `bigger`, you set the low end to 50, after just being told that is too small?